# Why is my post method not receiving the data that it is sent?

Tags: c#, http-post, postman, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a post method, the parameter `School` is always null every time it is being called. I make sure to send the right data across, I am using Postman, but when I inspect it with a breakpoint, I get a null object.

What I send with Postman:

```
{
    "Id": "",
    "Name": "Test"
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] School school)
{
    try
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var schoolData = Mapper.Map<School, Data.School>(school);

        var schoolModel = _schoolRepository.AddSchool(schoolData);

        return CreatedAtRoute("GetSchool", new { id = schoolModel }, schoolModel);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return LogException(e);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class School
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Class> Classes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `""` is not a valid `Guid`. If you don't want to send an `Id`, exclude it from the model binding

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yeah you are right, i just thought since there is no required attribute on the "Id", it should just let it pass. you can add this as an answer and ill mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your model requires a `Guid` and you are sending an `empty string`:

```
"Id": ""
```

Regardless of the `Id` not being `[Required]`, the model still cannot parse the data. What you can do, however, is to exclude it from binding:

```
public IActionResult Post([FromBody][Bind(Include = nameof(School.Name))] School school)
```

Or, a better option is to use a ViewModel. In this case, however, since you only have one property, I'd just use this:

```
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]string name)
```